# Sql server remove special character and convert it into int

Tags: sql, sql-server

$119,157.20

how to convert this value to int to use it in sum function

tried REPLACE(C.Salaries,'$',''),',','') it removes the $ and , but there is a special char '.' i cant convert it into float or int and i cant use round function also as its in varchar

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to float.- this is the error i am getting

Comment: you should have explained that he needs to remove the dollar sign first

Comment: @Stu your comment is misleading, as a reader things to convert the hole string into float.

Comment: @Stu i see that you can't follow, but the user tried to convert the hole string including $ to float, so he missunderstood your comment, and so it is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *money* as an intermediate cast:

```
select Cast(Cast('$119,157.20' as money) as int)
```